# Save a numpy array to csv with a string header

Tags: arrays, numpy, header, pandas, export-to-csv

I have a large-ish numpy array containing floats, which I save as a csv file with np.savetxt("myFile.csv", myArray, delimiter=",")

Now, as the array has many columns and it can become hard to remember what is what, I want to add a string header to the array before exporting it. Since numpy doesn't accept strings in float arrays, is there a trick to accomplish this?

[Solution]
Thanks to Cyborg's advice, I managed to make this work installing Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(A) # A is a numpy 2d array
df.to_excel("A.xls", header=C,index=False) # C is a list of string corresponding to the title of each column of A
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `header` argument (the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)):

```
numpy.savetxt(fname, X, delimiter=' ', header='')
```

But you may prefer [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) if you are actually dealing with a table.

Comment: I am indeed dealing with a 2d array, this is why I believed the 'header' attribute wouldn't work. I'll try panda! Cheers!

Comment: To save current fields as headers: `np.savetxt(path, X, delimiter=',', header= ','.join(X.dtype.names))`